# Do size of data from api response affect the speed of application that fetching data from that api?

Tags: api

I am Building A App , where I have to show categories of a Products , is there any changes in performance of app on the basis of data size coming from that if there are 10 categories coming from the api response vs there are 70 categories coming from that response , Do the size of response affect the performance of applictaion??

Comment: Are you just asking if larger amounts of data take more time to transfer/process than smaller amounts of data?  Because.... yes.  More of something is more than less of something.

Comment: Yes, more of something is more than less of something. However, the difference may not be one that is noticeable in your app. If your app responds in 46ms in one case, and in 47ms in another, does it matter? This is why you should make your code work first, and then figure out it if it's going fast enough.

Comment: ``` serializablestateinvariantmiddleware took 45ms , which is more than warning threshold of 32ms ``` this is warning i am getting in app and i notised slow down in application

Comment: what do you mean by make your code work first ? i didn't get it

Answer (score 1):

Of course! Response size drives performance. Imagine having a GET API that withdraws all the data from the table. If you have millions of rows, this is going to result into large chunk of response data. Depending upon what your maxresponsize is configured in your web server, the data will be returned or web server will simply fail to write it to wire.

Not only this results into large response size, the speed of accessing your data store will increase too. I have seen some badly written GET APIs scanning through the entire SQL Server table, millions of rows, resulting into a query that would execute for more than 30 seconds. All this time, the calling application is waiting for response, degrading its performance. Increase the number of parallel requests and you will run into other problems related to memory consumption, connection pool performance issues etc. These are just symptoms, the root cause of the problem is that massive chunk of data that is being read.

Ideally, an application should extract only the part of data that it needs to hand over to the user, i.e. it should compose queries in such a manner that filtering, compaction etc. happens on the database side, not on the application side. Database is the best tool to handle data, not application code.

There is host of other problems if you start drilling into paging, chunked responses, etc.

This is why API design is an important topic of discussion.

Comment: So i am using a get categories api , is there any difference from between fetching just  7 categories and 70 categories

Comment: What is the actual number of categories the user needs? If he/she needs 7 categories, and rest are being displayed in the grid for the sake of it, then of course it is waste of bandwidth and processing time. You also need to consider how many times this API is getting called. For example, if you are displaying all 70 categories every time the user visits your home page - which happens every few seconds, but user actually works with only the latest 10 categories all the time, then you should consider restructuring your API such that user gets an option to choose how much data he/she extracts.

Comment: 7 vs 70 categories shouldn't really matter in the grand scheme of things. Instead of querying your api for the next 7 categories it totally makes sense to get the 70 categories and paginate through it if thats what you are doing.

Comment: @Baz1nga : That is why I am asking what is the actual number of categories the user is going to need. Some times it is difficult to predict this number and this is where paged response makes sense. However if the criteria is well defined, for example, all categories that begin with A - there is just no point in selecting all 70 (or whatever) and showing them alphabetically in a paged response. Thats just wasting bandwidth.